# OWL API save ontology if reasoner is consistent and changes occurred

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, owl-api, pellet

I have an ontology that I need to save on file if and only if some changes occured and the reasoner (pellet in my case) is consistent with these changes. So i write:

```
 reasoner.flush(); //sync reasoner
 if(reasoner.isConsistent())
 manager.saveOntology(ontos[1], new RDFXMLDocumentFormat(), IRI.create((new   File(file)).toURI()));
```

I would synchronize Pellet only if the ontology has been modified, than if it is consistent synchronize it and apply changes. Any idea how to proceed?
Thank you

(Edit: I use manager.applyChange method in order to modify the ontology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used reasoner.getPendingChanges().isEmpty() to check for new changes with a buffering reasoner (with a non bufferd one changes apply automatically).

Comment: Another solution is to add an ontology change listener to the ontology manager. However your solution has the advantage of not requiring a flush.

Comment: Thank your for your feedback. If I use a non buffering reasoner and the reasoner itself as change listener, i.e. with manager.addOntologyChangeListener( reasoner ), how can I check for changes ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with just a non buffering reasoner and no other listener.

Comment: That sounds plausible since it is a " non buffering" reasoner. Thank you !